# iptables failed with " iptables v1.4.21: Couldn't load match `-d':No such file or directory" message

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, iptables

I am running kernel 3.14.18 and using iptables 1.4.21, built with these options `--static-enable --disable-shared.`

When I run this command:

```
/sbin/iptables -A PREROUTING  -m -d 127.3.0.2/24 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1 -p udp -dport 69
```

I get this error message:

```
iptables v1.4.21: Couldn't load match `-d':No such file or directory
```

Can anyone help explain what I am missing?

Comment: More info: I have a host system with 2 interfaces, eth0 and eth1. eth0 will receive packets with ip of 127.3.x.x. I want to forward these packets to go out of eth1 to a server (10.0.1). eth1 has ip of 192.168.0.100.  the server needs to see the packets as if they are coming from the host (192.168.0.100).

I think I can remove -m flag, but when i do, I am getting this error:
 
   iptables v1.4.21: multiple -d flags not allowed

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but for others who come across this via searches....

The -m option is to specify a module to load.  Correcting this and the --dport vs -dport mentioned by Augusto you may want.

```
/sbin/iptables -A PREROUTING -m udp -d 127.3.0.2/24 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1 -p udp --dport 69
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `--dport` instead `-dport` (missing one `-`)